# calculate gaze velocity in VR using normalized direction

Tags: physics, virtual-reality, normalize, denormalized

I'd like to calculate 3d velocity vector of user eye movement in a VR space.
For gaze data, I have my gaze with a normalized gaze origin and a normalized gaze direction.
How can I use the normalized gaze direction to calculate my velocity in 3d?

Thanks